# Sync local storage with online database, swift, xcode

Tags: android, ios, database, xcode, storage

I got a problem. I have to develop an iOS application that access to a simple xml online database and that store those data in a local storage remaining synchronized with it. I have a Parse account if that can help. (The application should work on Android too, so an universal solution would be great).

In simple terms, the user doesn't access the network sometimes, so I have to keep a local copy of the database that is online and, whenever it access the network, I have to check the version of the database online, and if newer download it and update the local copy. Which kind of local storage should I use? Which kind of online storage should I use? (Xml was just an idea) Can I use parse for this? Is there an online storage suitable for android too?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We are using sqlite android and ios. Using sql from server side. Webservice for connection.